# Blazor .net version compatibility issues

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor

So i thought Blazor supported .net core as well as .net standard. Meaning I can create projects that are .net standard or .net core and be able to reference them both in a Blazor app.

I remember hearing about this in a Microsoft blazor video.
Is this still supported or is this just a lie (as i am not able to do this)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 2):

Server side Blazor supports Asp.Net Core. But Blazor client side supports only .net standard, as the run time mono, compiled to WebAssembly and run on the browser, is .Net Framework compatible. It is expected that in the future mono run-time will be swapped with .Net Core compatible run-time.

It is not clear what is the issue you are talking about. What are you not able to do ?